# InitializeComponent returns a null reference when I add this line of code to my ComboBox selection event

Tags: c#, wpf

My `InitializeComponent();` line returns an error when I add the following line to my ComboBoxItem Selection event:

```
namespace NewProject
{
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ComboBoxItem_Selected_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //same for ComboBoxItem_Selected_2,3
        {
            TextBlock_ComboBoxes.Text = ("Combo Box Number: 1");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the text of a TextBlock based on which ComboBoxItem selected.

XAML Code:

```
<ComboBox FontFamily="Arial" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Combo Box Number 1" IsSelected="True" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Combo Box Number 2" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Combo Box Number 3" Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected_3"/>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_ComboBoxes" Text="Combo Box Number: 1"/>
```

This Xaml code is contained within a page that is within a frame that is within a window. These are the page properties:

```
<Page x:Class="NewProject.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600"
Title="Page 1">
```

Comment: Note that the SelectionChanged event may be fired before the TextBlock_ComboBoxes field is initialized. Check it for null.

Comment: @mjwills the exception is exactly this: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`
@Clemens yep it returns a null error but what am I supposed to check exactly, using non-technical terms because I'm a rookie at programming.

Comment: @mjwills I have provided the code you asked for to replicate the problem. I will see if this code fixes my program. Edit: Yep it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `InitializeComponent` the SelectionChanged event may be fired before the `TextBlock_ComboBoxes` field is initialized. You should check if the field is `null`:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_Selected_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBlock_ComboBoxes != null)
    {
        TextBlock_ComboBoxes.Text = ("Combo Box Number: 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It worked! But I still do not understand why it would be null in the first place.

Comment: All fields that correspond to `x:Name` declarations in XAML are initialized by InitializeComponent, i.e. they are null before InitializeComponent sets them. When your ComboBox is declared in XAML before the TextBlock and has a SelectionChanged handler that is fires immediately during its initialization, the TextBlock field may still be null.